# How come my time-value comparison is not working properly?

Tags: php

```
if (
    isset($get['when'])
    && !empty($get['when'])
    && !strtotime($get['when'])
    && strtotime($get['when']) < time()
)
```

Renders false for forexample  `strtotime($get['when']) = 2010-12-06`, this is less than time() ofc.

If I remove  `&& !empty($get['when'])` it works fine. Any suggestions why?

Comment: `!strtotime($get['when'])` will always evaluate to `false` if you pass a time after `1.1.1970 00:00:00`, making the whole expression `false`. You can easily test it: `var_dump(!strtotime('2010-12-06'));` gives you `bool(false)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is `!strtotime($get['when'])`. `strtotime` only returns false on failure and all other values are considered `true` so your statement is always false. I think you want:

```
(strtotime($get['when']) !== false)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is realy interesting part of code *green*

```
&& !strtotime($get['when'])  && strtotime($get['when'])
```

Comment: To be or not to be, that is the question.